# How to pass a parameter to a nodeJS fs callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I try to pass a parameter to nodejs fs callback function, but in the callback function, it can not access the parameter, like following:

I try to pass index to "line" event callback, but it fails, the index inside the callback is undefined. Seems the closure is not correct?

How to solve this?

```
function readLog(path, index) {

    var rd = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream(path),
        output: process.stdout,
        terminal: false
    });

    console.log("index: " + index);
    rd.on('line', function (lineContent) {
        console.log("index1: " + index);
        if (lineContent.indexOf("keyword") > -1) {
            keyword = "keyword " + index;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: According to your code as written, the callback function is inside `readLog` and thus does have access to `index`. Is the callback function not actually defined inside `readLog`? (Note that if you're adding an `index`parameter to the callback and din't include that in your question code, that `index` argument will be `undefined` and block access to the outer-scope `index`.)

Comment: The callback define in the `readLog` function. I don't add the `index` parameter to the callback, I just want the callback can get the `index` in `readLog`.

Comment: Both the `console.log()` statements in your code should have access to the `index` argument passed to `readLog()` just fine.  You don't "pass" the `index` value to the `rd.on()` callback.  You just access it directly from the parent scope (that's how closures in javascript work).  If this isn't your issue, then please clarify what your problem actually is.

Comment: I try to run, but the output is **index: 0 index1: undefined
index1: undefined**, the `console.log()` cannot access the `index`